# Discussion leading to Suzuki's Fractal decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Defining $S_2(x) = e^{(x/2) A}e^{xB}e^{(x/2)A}$. In a paper I am reading, author Masuo Suzuki claims that

1)$S_2(x) = e^{(x/2) A}e^{xB}e^{(x/2)A} = e^{x(A+B) + x^3R_3 + x^5R_5 + \cdots}$ where $R_{3+2k}$ are some matrices for $k \geq 0$.

His reasoning that the even-order terms vanish in the exponent of the right hand side of equation 1) is that $S_2(x)S_2(-x)=  e^{x/2 A}e^{xB}e^{x/2A}e^{-x/2 A}e^{-xB}e^{-x/2A} = I$. I'm not sure how these two are related. Any insights why this is the case would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the some branch of the matrix logarithm, we can state that the exponent in question is $\log[S_2(x)]$, and we want to show that this exponent is equal to 
$$
\log[S_2(x)] = x(A + B) + x^3 R_3 + x^5R_5 + \cdots
$$
for some matrices $R_k$.  Assuming that $\log[S_2(x)]$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $x = 0$, this is equivalent to showing that the function $\log[S_2(x)]$ is **odd**, that is, that $\log[S_2(-x)] = -\log[S_2(x)]$.

I will leave it to you to verify that because $S(x)S(-x) = I$, it follows that $\log[S_2(-x)] = -\log[S_2(x)]$.

Comment: Well assuming that the log of a product is the sum of the logs, knowing that $e^{0}= I$, the result follows.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the expression for $S_2$. In the paper it doesn't say whether the $R_{3k+2}$ are complex numbers or whether they are matrices (in fact it doesn't say what they are at all). Which of those two options makes more sense?

Comment: I would think that they’re matrices